# How to add arbitrary attributes to an angular directive for data validation

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am attempting to create an angular directive that will be a custom tag for input fields in our application.  Essentially what it will do is create the label, input field and the various bootstrap classes so there is a consistent look to them.

Along with that I would like it if I could add the various data validators that are appropriate for the particular input (such as required and custom validators) as attributes of the custom tag and then have those added to the input field and thus perform validation on that.

I have figured out a way that appears to put the attributes on the input field and the custom validator is getting called and properly evaluating the data, but the form never seems to think that the data is invalid.  I think I am having a scope problem where the input being invalid is being set on the directive's scope rather than the parent scope but I'm not 100% sure about that and even if it is the problem I don't know how to fix it.

Here's a sample of what I'd like one of the tags to look like

```
<textinput ng-model="TestValue" name="TestValue" text="Label Text" config="GetConfigurationForm()" ngx-ip-address required></textinput>
```

which I want to generate something like

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error': IsInvalid() }">
        <label for="{{name}}" class="control-label">{{text}}</label>
        <input id="{{name}}" type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="ngModel" name="{{name}}" ngx-ip-address required>
    </div>
</div>
```

Note that the ngx-ip-address and required have been moved to the input field attributes.

My controller looks like the following (sorry it's so long)

```
var app = angular.module('test', []);

app.directive('ngxIpAddress', function()
{
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function(scope, element, attributes, ngModel)
        {
            ngModel.$validators.ngxIpAddress = function(modelValue, viewValue)
            {
                // Value being blank is OK
                if (ngModel.$isEmpty(modelValue))
                    return true;

                // If the string starts with a character then
                // this is not valid
                if (isNaN(parseInt(viewValue[0])))
                    return false;

                var blocks = viewValue.split(".");
                if(blocks.length === 4)
                {
                    return blocks.every(function(block)
                    {
                        return parseInt(block, 10) >= 0 && parseInt(block, 10) <= 255;
                    });
                }

                return false;
            };
        }
    };
});

    app.directive('textinput', function ()
    {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            scope: {
                //@ reads the attribute value, = provides two-way binding, & works with functions
                ngModel: '=',
                name: '@',
                text: '@',
                config: '&'
            },
            controller: function($scope) {
                $scope.IsInvalid = function()
                {
                    var getConfigurationFunction = $scope.config();
                    if (!getConfigurationFunction || !getConfigurationFunction[$scope.name])
                        return false;

                    return getConfigurationFunction[$scope.name].$invalid;
                };
            },
            link: function(scope, element, attributes) {
                var inputElement = element.find("input");
                for (var attribute in attributes.$attr)
                {
                    if (attribute !== "ngModel"
                        && attribute !== "name"
                        && attribute !== "text"
                        && attribute !== "config")
                    {
                        inputElement.attr(attribute, attributes[attribute]);
                    }
                }
            },
            template: '<div class="row">' +
                '<div class="form-group" ng-class="{ \'has-error\': IsInvalid() }">' +
                '<label for="{{name}}" class="control-label">{{text}}</label>' +
                '<input id="{{name}}" type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="ngModel" name="{{name}}">' +
                '</div>' +
                '</div>'
        };
    });

    app.controller(
        "TestController",
        [
            "$scope",
            function TestController(_scope)
            {
                _scope.TestValue = "TestTest";
                _scope.GetConfigurationForm = function()
                {
                  return _scope.ConfigurationForm;
                };
            }
        ]
    );
```

If I put the attributes in the actual template then everything works as expected and the control turns red if the data isn't an ip address.  When I add the attributes by moving them that doesn't work.

Here is a plunkr showing what I've got so far:  http://plnkr.co/edit/EXkz4jmRif1KY0MdIpiR

Here is a plunkr showing what I'd like the end result to look like where I've added the tags to the template rather than the tag:  http://plnkr.co/edit/mUGPcl1EzlHUiMrwshCr

To make this even more fun, in the future I will actually need to pass in a value to the data validation directives from the outside scope as well, but I'd like to get this working first.

Answer (score 1):

[Here](http://plnkr.co/edit/L3IVbxKIlh5GzKCPuRAb?p=preview) you may find the correct answer.

The reasons of this issue are:

1. the `attr` will convert the attribute from `ngxIpAddress` to `ngxipaddress`, namely from the uppercase to lowercase, you can find this issue from this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10390346/why-is-jquery-auto-lower-casing-attribute-values). To solve it, just pass `ngx-ip-address` as parameter for function `attr`.
2. `$compile(inputElement)(scope);` need to be added into directive, when one directive is used in another directive. Here is one [link](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile).