# Case sensitive jQuery attribute not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, attributes, case-sensitive

I am running into an issue where I would like to remove/change the attribute `viewBox`(note the uppercase "B") in an SVG via jQuery.

My code is:

```
$('svg').removeAttr('viewBox').attr('viewBox', '0 0 963 630');
```

But what is appearing is this `viewbox` (with a lowercase "b." )In order for what I am doing to work, it needs to be a capital "B." How do I add a case-sensitive attribute?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Don't use jQuery. Use the DOM.

Comment: [Here's an answer from 2015 about jquery doing toLowerCase and not caring, but it has a workaround.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28876796/3585500) Actually the answer above that might work, which is update 2 or `$("svg")[0].setAttribute("viewBox", "0 0 166 361");`

Comment: @HereticMonkey So are you saying that you can force HTML attribute to be case-sensitive with vanilla JS?

Comment: @jom yes, See [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/s6gq134o/) for an example.

Comment: @HereticMonkey - that worked. Did: `document.getElementsByTagName("svg")[0].setAttribute("viewBox", "0 0 963 630");` instead. :)

Comment: Feel free to accept the duplicate closure, as it says basically the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('svg').attr('viewBox','').attr('viewBox', '0 0 963 630');
```

OR use native Javascript `setAttribute`

```
$('svg')[0].setAttribute('viewBox','0 0 963 630')
```

Comment: That first line is almost exactly the same as the OPs...